# variance implementation applied to calculate the standard deviation?

Tags: java, math, statistics

I'm using the Math-library in Java to calculate some statistics. My questions concerns the class `DescriptiveStatistics`

```
 org.apache.commons.math.stat.descriptive.DescriptiveStatistics
```

If I use the method `setVarianceImpl(...)`, is it applied to the calculation of the standard deviation (`getStandardDeviation(...)`). I guess so, but I cannot find any documentation on this?

Correct me, if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is a constructor

```
DescriptiveStatistics(double[] initialDoubleArray)
```

which i think you might want to use that takes the raw stats data. Then use the function:

```
getStandardDeviation()
```

or

```
getVariance()
```

The documentation is [here](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/stat/descriptive/package-summary.html) and looks complete.

Hope that helps.

Comment: this does not answer my question. I got source code, which tried to implement the calculation of the MAD (median absolute deviation) istead of the standard deviation. They used the `setVarianceImpl`-method to get the MAD instead of the standard deviation when calling `getStandardDeviation`.